# Unity XMPP Chat

Tags: c#, android, ios, unity-game-engine, xmpp

I am new to Unity and implementing a XMPP chat there for the first time. I am trying since 20 days but nothing seems to work for me. I have tried the below libraries with special regard to:

**[Jabber Unity Networking](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/61729)**

I have purchased this code for $30 and implemented it, but the issue is that it is working fine in Unity editor but when I export it as `.apk` for Android  and `.app` for iOS then it is not working. The XMPP connection fails for real devices with the following error log for Android : `getifaddrs`

I also tried to work with libraries suggested in this **[XMPP library list for C#](http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.html)**, but was not able to find a solution there.

**More References:**

- [P*Works Internet Toolkit](https://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/)
- [jabber.net](https://code.google.com/archive/p/jabber-net/)
- [Sharp.Xmpp](https://github.com/pgstath/Sharp.Xmpp)
- [Ubeity](https://github.com/ubiety/xmpp)

---

Other possible paid reference that I did not consider:

- [agsXMPP SDK](http://www.ag-software.net/) - But this is paid
- [MatriX](http://www.ag-software.net/) -  But this is paid

Also tried to create a plugin for Unity using native iOS code of XMPP chat but it also fails.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unity is not 100% compatible with the full .NET Framework. Mainly the networking code needs some tweaks to run fine on all Unity platforms.

You either have to choose a library with full Unity support (according to the authors), or make the adjustments yourself in those libraries.

I am the author of the MatriX and agsXMPP libraries. MatriX is fully compatible with Unity and used by many developers with Unity. I have not ported agsXMPP to Unity, and cannot speak for the other libraries you listed above.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and respect your answer to clear the situation and I have successfully implemented iOS Plugin for Unity and now working on Android Plugin.